# Create task group in Airflow that takes different arguments

Tags: python, kubernetes, airflow

I have a `KubernetesPodOperator` that will take some arguments to run a python. script.

This script will need to run for a number of arguments parallel. My current approach of using loop over 2 lists cause the following error:

> airflow.exceptions.DuplicateTaskIdFound: Task id 'blahblah'

This is my current code:

```
start = DummyOperator(task_id="start_job", dag=dag)
end = DummyOperator(task_id="end_job", dag=dag)

arguments_list = [
    ["a", "b", "c", "2023"],
    ["d", "e", "f", "2023"] # more of these
]

for args in arguments_list:
    for i, v in enumerate(args):
        task_id = (
            f"my_unique_task_id_{args[0]}_{args[1]}_{args[2]}_{args[3]}"
        )

        extract_data = KubernetesPodOperator(
            namespace=NAMESPACE,
            image="my_image",
            image_pull_policy="Always",
            name="my_name",
            task_id=task_id.lower(),
            in_cluster=False,
            get_logs=True,
            env_vars=task_env_vars,
            secrets=[secret_file],
            cmds=["/bin/bash", "-c"],
            arguments=[
                f"{RUN_SCRIPT} --args1 {args[0]} --args2 {args[1]} --args3 {args[2]} --year {args[3]}"
            ],
            dag=dag,
        )

        start >> extract_data >> end
```

I want to create DAGs for all elements in the list and run them independently of each others.

Comment: maybe it makes sense to use dynamic task mapping here https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.6.1/authoring-and-scheduling/dynamic-task-mapping.html